# MvcRazorToPdf save as MemoryStream or Byte[]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, pdf-generation, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcrazortopdf

I'm using MvcRazorToPdf in a Azure website and create my PDF's and output them in the browser.

Now i'm creating a new function to directly email the PDF as attachment (without output them in the browser).

Does anybody know if it is possible to save the PDF (with MvcRazorToPdf) as a MemoryStream or Byte[]?

Comment: I can't help you with the MVC part but the last line of code in `PdfActionResult.cs` has the `byte` array and `MemoryStream` that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle this in ResultFilter, I used below code to allow user to download file and prompt for download popup, in this way you can grab all your memory stream and store somewhere to send email afterwords.

`public class ActionDownloadAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Report.pdf");
            base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }`

```
 [ActionDownload]
 public ActionResult GeneratePdf()
 {
       List<Comment> comments = null;

        using (var db = new CandidateEntities())
        {
            comments = db.Comments.ToList();
        }

        return new PdfActionResult("GeneratePdf", comments);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something like that. So basically I have not been changing my method to output PDF. What I have done is used restsharp to make request at URL where I get PDF then what you have is in lines of (this is partial code only so you can get idea )

```
var client = new RestClient(IAPIurl);
var request = new RestRequest(String.Format(IAPIurl_generatePDF, targetID), Method.GET);
RestResponse response = (RestResponse) client.Execute(request);

// Here is your byte array 
response.RawBytes
```

Otherwise you can use my answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121823/mvcrazortopdf-save-pdf-to-location-or-blob-and-then-download/29387409#29387409) where I discussed directly returning a file.

Hope this helps!